# ArchLinux | Login password does not work after creating new user account

Tags: arch-linux, users, root, non-root-user, useradd

I am trying Arch Linux for learning more stuff faster and not having GUI that bothers me, so that I can focus on learning stuff from Linux itself and the terminal.
Since I was working with the default root@host I decided to create a new user.
After creting the new user with a password and a dedicated user folder I rebooted and then neither the password for the root nor the newly created user worked...
Maybe I did it wrong and don't understand how accounts work.

I used the following line to create the user in Arch.

```
useradd me -Umr -b /home -d /home/me -p newpass
```

Did I do something wrong or something? It seems i'm not able to login now from neither accounts.

My intention was to create a default user account that is not /root so that I am not always logged in as root user, so that when I boot up, the newly creted account pass is asked.

Comment: What happens when you try to log in? What error do you get? Is it the same error? What was `password`? Was it the actual password or did you encrypt it first?

Comment: As Ned64 has pointed out, -p is normally for adding encrypted passwords as seen in /etc/shadow, This shouldn't effect the root user though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-p` parameter to `useradd` expects an encrypted password.  It would be bad security practice to give a password in a command line. This is because every process on the system can read all command lines (except when using containers). So, the `useradd` command will not accept a plaintext password but force you to encrypt it before giving it as a parameter.

Set the password interactively afterwards:

```
passwd me
```

Comment: Just tested it - ArchLinux requires a password while Ubuntu will ask interactively

Comment: @Lorthas `-p` does not encrypt the password but you need to pass an encrypted password! So, you do not say `useradd ... -p mypass` but something like `useradd ... -p $6$/idugaTo$pdm....`.

Comment: @msrd0 ah, OK. I deleted your comment since I tested (also on Arch) and saw that it expects a password and since the OP is using Arch, I figured it would only be confusing to leave the comment.

Comment: @terdon Why remove useful comments where people look for a solution? I don't get it.

Comment: @ned64 because the comment was suggesting that `-p` with no argument would prompt you. Apparently, it does so on Ubuntu, but not in Arch so the comment was misleading. Also, I admit I didn't know it was true for Ubuntu. I just tested, saw that it didn't work and deleted the comment.